# Use AutoHotKey to Copy Data from DST (A Text Based Interface)

Tags: autohotkey

All day long, I have to:
 1. copy an account number from Excel,
 2. paste into a text based interface program called DST (the interface almost looks like Command Prompt),
 3. hit enter
 4. copy the name and address from DST and
 5. paste into the corresponding form field in an Adobe Acrobat form.

It looks like AutoHotKey will automate me doing steps 1-3 & 5, but will it work in step 4, copying the name and address within the text interface (DST)?

I ask b/c I normally have to use my cursor to highlight each part of the name and address and copy/paste into the Adobe form, so will AutoHotKey know where to start and stop copying the first name, then the middle initial, and last name, and each part of the address, etc., even though each customer's name and address is different lengths?

If AutoHotKey will work, can you tell me some of the command names that will help do this so I can do some research on them to help get me started?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You should be able to use the string and RegEx functions to scrape the name and address from text in the clipboard

Comment: @JimU Thank you for listing some functions to get me started. I will do some research and test out the code I come up. Thank you, again.